# Run multiple nginx servers on different ports by different users

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Let me describe the problem I need to solve:

There is a sandbox server (Debian), each developer has own user account on it. I need to provide an easy and quick way of running/stopping any number of nginx instances on different ports for different projects. These will be used only by QA for testing purposes.

**For example:**
Alice runs a server on `sandbox.example.com:4001` that points to folder `/home/alice/web/staging_2014_09_24`

Bob runs three servers:
`sandbox.example.com:5123 -> /home/bob/www/dev_2014_09_24_login_fix
sandbox.example.com:5124 -> /home/bob/www/staging_2014_09_20
sandbox.example.com:5126 -> /home/bob/www/testing_release_features`

Each of these folders would contain some branch of PHP code from Git.

**Questions:**
1. Is there an easy, common way to do this? The solution I now think about is writing a script, which would create a parameterized config for nginx and then run a new server instance using it. It could be executed like: `./serverManager start www/staging_2014_09_20 5124` or `./serverManager stop 5124`
2. Do I also need to spawn new php-fpm process for every server or I can use one common instance?

Comment: You do realise that since those nginx instances don't listen to privileged network ports, they don't have to be started by root. Bob and Alice can (in theory) start their own instances if you configure each instance to not need access to root owned directories...

Comment: I know this. But the question is how to start and manage them really quickly - it's the task each developer will have to do daily and I don't think that editing nginx.conf file manually for every host is a best idea.

Comment: Docker? You could even automate that, having Jenkins start them.